# JPA use of maps and inserting multiple entries

Tags: java, jpa, mapping, persistence

Looking at example1 at http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MapKey:

I have a collection of child entities in a parent entity as shown below in pseudo code.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @MapKey(name="childId")
    protected Map<Long, Child> children;
}
```

where @MapKey and "childId" is the primary key in the CHILD table.

I write code to add an new child entry to the map in the parent with a null childId.
On save jpa gets a new id from a sequence as described on the Child Entity and inserts a new record correctly in the child table.

However if I want to add multiple new entries how do I do this?

keys are unique so only one entry with a null key value is allowed.
Or do I call select on the sequence manually to get a childId for each map entry?

Comment: am i missing something here....I wonder..... google doesn't return any examples of inserting records using the primary key of the object in the map as the mapKey.....